# Save first few lines from files to cvs that are located in different directories

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

my problem is that I need to read specific lines from a large number of text files from different folders and save them in one CSV file per author of files, folder structure looks like this:

```
main---author1--file1
    |         --....
    |         --file1000         
    ---author2--file1
    |         --....
    |         --file1000  
    |--...
    ---author27--file1
               --....
               --file1000
```

I managed to read all files from the different directories and get authors names from the folder names, also read 1-3 lines from the file, but I struggle to find a way to save these lines to CSV.

```
import os
path = '/content/Data2/STN_INV/'
authors = os.listdir('/content/Data2/STN_INV/'); 
for auth in authors:  
    files = os.listdir(path+auth+'/');
    tmpD,tmpA=[],[]
    for file in files:
        f=open(path+auth+'/'+file, 'r')
        data = f.read()[0:3]
        print(path+auth+'/'+file, os.path.exists(path+auth+'/'+file),'size',len(data),auth)
        tmpD.append(data)
        tmpA.append(auth)
```

Is there an easy way to do so in google colab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To traverse through folder, you can use:

```
import glob
glob.glob('main/author*/file*')
```

For saving purpose (according to your code):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = '/content/Data2/STN_INV/'
authors = os.listdir('/content/Data2/STN_INV/')
for auth in authors:
    files = os.listdir(path+auth+'/')
    tmp = []
    for file in files:
        f = open(path+auth+'/'+file, 'r')
        data = f.readlines()[:3]
        print(path+auth+'/'+file, os.path.exists(path +
              auth+'/'+file), 'size', len(data), auth)
        tmp.append([auth]+data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(tmp, columns=["Author", "Line1", "Line2", "Line3"])
    df.to_csv(f"{auth}.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is a good solution for saving all authors data in one file, but I need a solution to save files data to csv per author

Comment: Ok, I have pdate as per your requirement. Now you can have a look @hixi22745

Comment: I believe I made a mistake thinking that I was reading the first 3 lines of the file, apparently it was the first 3 symbols, because of that I'm getting an error: "can only concatenate list (not "str") to list". Now I need to find a proper way to read lines

Comment: So you can use ```f.readlines()```